# Tem como diminuir as bordas dos formulários do google?

Tags: google

Olá, pessoal.

Fiz um formulário no Google e resolvi deixar no meu site, como captura de e-mails. Mas estou com um problema. Se deixo na barra laterial, ele fica apertado, não cabe direito. Se deixo abaixo dos posts (como neste: https://colunastortas.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/modernidade-liquida-o-que-e/ ) ele também pede barra de rolagem.

Teria como eu retirar essas margens do formulário (acima e dos lados, por exemplo) pra deixar o conteúdo mais colado nos espaços em que eu botei o formulário? Tipo, retirar o padding-top e padding-left do title e do conteúdo, assim como das perguntas?

O código do formulário é

```
<iframe
 src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1nY8yCiEQaGCwfInOiRe8xFttY9Y9NB1VqAfDfouTC2w/viewform?embedded=true" 
 frameborder="0" width="640" height="300" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Cara recomendo que faça seu próprio formulário, é bem simples e você tem mais liberdade pra alterar o layout e todas as outras coisas que quiser

Comment: De qualquer forma, edite a pergunta colocando o código pra ficar mais fácil ajuda-lo

Comment: Coloquei o código, tem uma parte de script no google forms, acho que lá daria pra eu colocar algum código.